# Как изменить отступ от края input для вводимого текста?

Tags: css, jsx

Текст расположен слишком близко к краю `input`, как можно его отдалить от него вправо?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

JSX:

```
      <form>
        <label htmlFor="email"></label>
        <input type="email" id="email" className="EnterForm" placeholder='Email' />

        <label htmlFor="password"></label>
        <input type="password" id="password" className="EnterForm" placeholder='Password' />

        <button type="submit">Войти</button>
      </form>
```

CSS:

```
  input.EnterForm{
    position: relative;
    background-color: yellowgreen;
    color: #fff;
    width: 85%;
    font-size: 13px;
    height: 35px;
    margin-bottom: 16px;
    left: 16px;
    border-radius: 11px;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    cursor: line;
  }
```

Comment: Добавить соответствующий padding.

Answer (score 2):

```
input::placeholder {
  padding-right: 20px; /* Устанавливаем отступ справа на 20 пикселей (или любое другое значение) */
}
```

Comment: Это отдаляет лишь placeholder, а текст остается там же. Если я сделаю также и для input, то оно просто увеличит его длину. Можно ли как-то задать внутри input зону, в которой будет писаться текст? Например слева и справа между текстом и краями input должны быть отступы в 20px. Я попробовал костыль: указать padding left и right 20px и ширину input уменьшить, это сработало, но как-то на душе плохо)

Answer (score 0):

Измените свойство `box-sizing` со значения `content-box`, оно применено для всех элементов по-умолчанию, на `border-box` для селектора `input`. Это позволит применить внутренний отсуп.

> Свойство `box-sizing` может принимать одно из двух значений – `border-box` или `content-box`. В зависимости от выбранного значения браузер по-разному трактует значение свойств `width/height`.

Можете подробнее прочитать об этих свойствах на [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing).

```css
 input {
    position: relative;
    background-color: yellowgreen;
    color: #fff;
    width: 85%;
    font-size: 13px;
    height: 35px;
    margin-bottom: 16px;
    left: 16px;
    border-radius: 11px;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    cursor: line;
    box-sizing: border-box; /** позволит добавить padding */
    padding: 1rem;
  }
```

```html
<form>
        <label htmlFor="email"></label>
        <input type="email" id="email" className="EnterForm" placeholder='Email' />

        <label htmlFor="password"></label>
        <input type="password" id="password" className="EnterForm" placeholder='Password' />

        <button type="submit">Войти</button>
      </form>
```